Unable to send BTC using Electrum - OP_EQUALVERIFY Error
I'm using Electrum to send BTC to my Trust Wallet, in this case I'm getting the following error:
The server returned an error transmitting the transaction.

Consider connecting to a different server, or upgrading Electrum.

Script failed an OP_EQUALVERIFY operation.


How could I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.
PS: I'm already using the last Electrum version.

This question is similar to: Bitcoin Script: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed Script failed an OP_EQUALVERIFY operation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
